# Error while connecting to Cloud SQL using jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have written a basic java code to connect to my Cloud SQL instance. I have added the mysql jar connector in this project.

```
import java.sql.*;

class MysqlCon {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://project-name:us-central1:test-instance", "username", "password");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from testing");
                while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
        con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to connect and receiving this exception

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "us-central1:test-instance"'.`

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: That is nit a valid name see this readme file https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory

Answer (score 2):

Thanks nbk for your comment. I was able to solve the issue by modifying the connection string and including this dependency in my maven project

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Updated connection string

`"jdbc:mysql:///testing?cloudSqlInstance=project-name:us-central1:test-instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=username&password=password"`

Comment: Please accept your own answer, in this way other members can identify yours as accepted and valid.